# How to disable mouse-wheel zoom in Atom Editor?

Tags: settings, zooming, atom-editor, mousewheel

I often zoom by accident and prefer zooming with 'strg' + '+'.

How can I disable the mouse-wheel zooming in Atom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be an option at the bottom of the 'Editor' Settings:

[image: Ctrl Scrolling option in Atom]